# Load variables from while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table which contains page content, each line of content has a page_id number

I want to load all the variables for the page I'm on, then display them where they need to be...

I'm naming the variables: div_1, div_2, div_3 etc etc

here's what I'm trying:

PHP

```
$home_p1 = mysql_query("select div_content from page_content where (page_id = '1');",$db);

$i=1;
while ($p1 = mysql_fetch_array($home_p1)){
$div_.$i = $p1[0];
$i++;
}
```

then throughout the page i can

```
echo $div_1;
blah blah blah
echo $div_2
blah blah blah
echo $div_3
etc etc
```

But I'm getting nothing back, I'm not even sure if this is the correct logic to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays.

```
$div[$i] = $p1[0];
```

And through the page you can:

```
echo $div[1];
blah blah blah
echo $div[2];
blah blah blah
echo $div[3];
etc etc
```

If you want to keep your structure structure then use:

```
$tempname = "div_".$i;
$$tempname=$p1[0];
```

For more details see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (first solution) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (second solution).

Answer (score 0):

organize it in arrays like this:

```
$home_p1 = mysql_query("select div_content from page_content where (page_id = '1');",$db);
$results = array();
$i=1;
while ($p1 = mysql_fetch_array($home_p1)){
    //$div_.$i = $p1[0];
    $results[] = $p1[0];
    $i++;
}
```

then you can access the first line by

```
echo $results[0]; // second by $results[1] and so on.
```

have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variables like this:

```
$div_.$i = $p1[0];
```

You should put them into an array like this:

```
$div_array = array();
```

then

```
$div_array[$i] = $p1[0];
```

Now you can output them by referencing the array directly:

```
echo $div_array[1];
```

Or else you can expand the array into variables using extract:

```
extract($div_array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'div_');
```

Now you have your $div_$i variables.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accopmlish what you are trying to, you should do something like next:

```
$home_p1 = mysql_query("select div_content from page_content where (page_id = '1');",$db);

$i=1;
while ($p1 = mysql_fetch_array($home_p1)){
  $name = 'div_' . $i;
  $$name = $p1[0];
  $i++;
}
```

You will get the list of variables with names $div_1, $div_2, etc.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

But the best way, as it was said, to use arrays.

```
$home_p1 = mysql_query("select div_content from page_content where (page_id = '1');",$db);

$i=1;
$divs = Array();
while ($p1 = mysql_fetch_array($home_p1)){
  $divs['div_' . $i] = $p1[0];
  $i++;
}
```